# My LTO-5 ultrium 3000 SAS external tape drive won't show up on my iMac

Tags: backup, macos, drivers

OK, so here is my problem. I got a HP LTO-5 ultrium 3000 SAS external tape drive from my boss and he said to connect it to my new iMac but when I connect it, it doesn't show up on my computer.

I'm really not good at this but I have searched for an answer online and haven't found one. I don't have ant specific information about the LTO-5 I have or where he bought it but he said that I had to install some program to make it work and I don't know what that program is. I asked my boss but he didn't remember what program it was.

It is connected via a ATTO Thunder Link. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Hint: It won't show up as a disk in the Finder, but you should see it in the System Report (About this Mac > More Info > System Report) as a thunderbolt device. What kind of backup software do you want to use? Does it report to not find an attached tape drive?

Comment: Thanks for that! I see now that the thunderbolt device is connected but it say that nothing is connected to it. Can you recommend any backup software? I can mention that the lto is linked to the thunder link via a sas-cable if that's any help.

Comment: This problem has been resolved, thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Please post your solution to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution to my problem was that I didn't have the software to use the LTO. I found that when I downloaded HP StoreOpen Standalone I could use the LTO without a problem.